# Reduce size and hide fragment with swipe like pager

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a tablet view with two fragments (sometimes three) side by side. Now I would like to implement hiding on fragment when the other fragment is flinged towards it.

I got this working now but I am just hiding one fragment when the second fragment receives an appropriate onFling event. However this just produces a hide with no visual feedback during the fling so it is hard for users to detect.

I would like to be able to use a similar motion to the ViewPager where flinging on the view (or slowly dragging it) moves it with the finger. But instead of moving from one view to another I would like one view to disappear and the other to be fully expanded. And the reverse where flinging to other way would slow start showing the second view.

Is there anything that allows me to animate the size of my fragment layout dynamically reacting to a touch event? Even if I have to create a new component ...

Any ideas?